# How can I keep field data from being escaped and preserve html and image styles in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, escaping, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-form-helper

I’m using CKEditor and KCFinder to build a relatively simple CMS. Currently, things are working pretty well. I noticed an issue, though, when I started integrating images into the mix. The links for the iamges are comign back wrong. It looks like CKEditor might be changing the quotes, etc, on me. It looks correct when I look in mysql but it doesn’t always look correct when I look in the editor but it’s definitely not. Most of the time it does, but this time it came back looking like this:

```
<img alt="" data-cke-saved-src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/287.jpg" 
     src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/287.jpg"
     200px;="" height:="" 287px;="" float:="" left;"="">i
```

For example, look at this page here: http://testosm.phpfogapp.com/pages/index/1/3/

I have all the code posted here: https://github.com/jshultz/monkey-cms in case you want to see what I was doing? Any feedback would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** 
I have turned on global_xss_filtering and the data is definitely cleaner now. all the styling was removed. Unfortunately. it’s almost perfect. Now, if I could just keep the image styling it would be perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was the XSS_Clean function. It was stripping out the styling. Good to know.